Update a field in a table when we choose it in othere table or a from related to other table
I have an access database, there is a table called "Place". (contain Place01, Place02, Place03)
The place table has 3 column: ID, Place and Status.
Status can be "Occupied" or "Empty".
In other table we can choose a place from the "place table".
I want to update the place status in the Place table to "Occupied" when we select it in other table and change it to "Empty" when we choose a date in other field in the same row.
Thanks a lot
nothing..............
